# How can i use lockForUpdate in laravel4 edit page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locking

Welcome ,
How can i using the

```
lockForUpdate
```

in my edit page with laravel4 restiful controller

Answer (score 0):

Well with such a general answer I can just give you a general answer:

```
$model = Model::where('id', $id)->lockForUpdate()->first();
```

Comment: thank u the problem  is when i use innodb laravel4  i want to lock the recored when updating the recored frem another person i make this query in edit page<pre>//   $cc = DB::select('select * from customers where transaction_id = '.$_GET['edit'].' FOR UPDATE');
$cc = Customer::where('transaction_id', $_GET['edit'])->lockForUpdate()->first();</pre>

Comment: What else do you need? Where are you having a problem?

Comment: the query done but not lock as when i login by seesion  can edit on a record and when i login by another session also can edit on same record !! not lock for update her the code of lock on edit function restful controller                  (        $customer = Customer::where('transaction_id', $id)->lockForUpdate()->first();
) thanx.v much

Comment: I don't think a MySQL lock for update is what you want to do in this situation. Consider adding a `locked` field in your db and set that to true as soon as someone opens the edit form.

Comment: can i code if the edit url open on session to prevent or hide edit btn on maintenance table ? as what u told have a bug that if close browser after open edit form